# date filter doesn't give the exact used 12-hour format in angualrJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to display date time using 12-hour format:'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm a'
The **expected result** is for ex.: **27-DEC-2016 12:30 AM**
The **actual result** is : **Dec 27, 2016**
The **old result** without using any formats is:**2016-12-22T13:22:00Z**

**HTML Code:**

```
{{pickuptime | date:defaultDateTimeFormat}}
```

**Controller Code:**

```
$scope.defaultDateTimeFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm a";
```

Comment: this code working fine, you have to be missing something more. Can you show the rest of your code

Comment: How do you get the `pickuptime ` variable?

Comment: defaultDateTimeFormat isn't a global variable, you have to specify the format in the filter. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: @RamblinRose it just holds the format i don't think this is the problem

Comment: @RamblinRose I've add the old result appeared to me without using any formats

Comment: @Yoan it is just a binding value been sent in the use of the directive

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.date = new Date();
  $scope.defaultDateTimeFormat = "dd-MMM-yy h:mm a";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  {{date | date:defaultDateTimeFormat}}
</div>
```

**With your input**

It is coming in 24 Hrs format

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.date = new Date();
  $scope.defaultDateTimeFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm a";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  {{date | date:defaultDateTimeFormat}}
</div>
```

See for more details [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: This is exactly how I wore my code! .. the controller holds the var defaultDateTimeFormat and I just use it in the HTML

Comment: @MoatazAmer Check the updated answer. It is showing in 24 Hrs with input as you mentioned in question